# django model set field default value from admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

#### models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
maximum_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=5)
```

Here I set maximum_limit default value is 5.

But I want to set a value which is also editable from admin and use here as a default value. (editable default value for model MyModel)

My initial approach is(not working). I want something like this.

```
class MySettings(models.Model):
mx_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=5)

class MyModel(models.Model):
maximum_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=MySettings.mx_limit)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, a maximum for a db value should be set with the proper attribute, namely [max_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.IntegerField.max_value).

However this would require a schemamigration everytime you want to change it. So what you really should be doing is dynamic form validation where your form checks for a setting (which should probably be saved in your database and not be statically stored in a module like Settings, which would require server restarts).

There are plenty examples [how to make a form validation more dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django%20dynamic%20form%20validation) on stackoverflow